# How to catch error in Django project on apache: 10048 "Address already in use"

Tags: python, django, apache

Python 2.5.2, Apache 2.2, Django 1.0.2 final

My Django app tries to connect to a certain port. When that port is busy, I get the error 10048 "Address already in use" from apache. I know where the error is coming from. How do I catch this apache error?

More info:

```
error at /report/5/2009/08/01/

(10048, 'Address already in use')

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.0.21/report/5/2009/08/01/
Exception Type:     error
Exception Value:    

(10048, 'Address already in use')

Exception Location:     C:\Python25\Lib\httplib.py in connect, line 683
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\httpd.exe
Python Version:     2.5.2
Python Path:    ['D:\\django\\system', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.5.egg', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\python_memcached-1.44-py2.5.egg', 'C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2\\htdocs', 'c:\\mapnik_0_6_0\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python25.zip', 'C:\\Python25\\Lib', 'C:\\Python25\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2\\bin', 'C:\\Python25', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\Program Files\\GeoDjango\\Django-1.0.2-final']
```

Server time:    don, 10 Sep 2009 11:20:45 +0200

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling `httplib.connect` directly from your code, then the `try`/`except` should be around that direct call. Or is the call happening indirectly...?  Unfortunately Apache is not giving you a stack trace, so if you're having problems locating exactly what call sequence is involved you could put a broad try/except at the highest level available to you, and save a printout of the traceback so you can identify the call site involved (or, edit your question to show the traceback, and we can help you locate it). See the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module in Python's standard library for more on how to format a traceback in an `except` clause.